# running a method within another method. python

Tags: python, methods, command, maya

I am calling a method within another. and the error for this script i am getting is

```
NameError: name 'mnDialog' is not defined
```

Is there a reason for it? I think it has something to do with executing a command which isn't on the global level. (i didn't have the impression that python has a global and local variable declaration.) What is the right syntax or the go around this?
thank you for your time.

---

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def mnProgRun():
    def mnDialog(*args):
        cmds.confirmDialog( title='Confirm', message='Are you sure?',button=['Yes','No'], defaultButton='Yes',cancelButton='No',dismissString='No' )
    def mnMakeWin():
        cmds.window( 'mnWin', title = 'testman', wh=(260,100))
        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=False, columnAlign='center')
        cmds.button( label="Yes,it works",align='center',width=120,height=25, backgroundColor=[0.5,1,0.5],command='cmds.scriptJob( event=["SelectionChanged","mnDialog"])')
        cmds.button( label="No, Thank You!",align='center',width=120,height=25, backgroundColor=[1,0.5,0.5],command='cmds.deleteUI("mnWin")')
    cmds.showWindow( 'mnWin' )
    mnMakeWin()
mnProgRun()
```

---

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `mnDialog` is not being looked up from `mnMakeWin`, you are passing the name and it gets looked up later when you are not in the correct scope.

It may work to pass the function in instead of the name. I don't have maya installed, so I can't try it.

Otherwise you'll have to define mnDialog in the global scope which seems like an odd restriction to me

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you give a small simple example of passing a function instead of a name, maybe with a print "hello" example.

Answer (score 1):

`mnDialog` is a local variable in `mnProgRun`.  It is not accessible outside the function scope.  If you want it to be, define it at the appropriate scope.

> (i didn't have the impression that python has a global and local variable declaration.)

You have the wrong impression.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i m learning something new all the time

Answer (score 1):

You should define `mnDialog` at the top level. It is not in the correct namespace.

Also, it's (almost) always unnecessarily complicating to nest functions in Python.

Comment: there is a reason for nesting it within the big method. so that maya can call and source it as one big method when it starts up, defining outside would cause it to not source it in the 1st place. would there be a go around for this?

Answer (score 0):

maya always have problems with scoops,
you may define mnDialog() and mnMakeWin() outside the function, at the top scoop level,
its maya problem not from python, as i faced problem when calling class methods from maya ui command (ex button event).

hope that will help you :)

##edit

import maya.cmds as cmds

```
def mnDialog(*args):

    cmds.confirmDialog( title='Confirm', message='Are you sure?',button=['Yes','No'],

                          defaultButton='Yes',cancelButton='No',dismissString='No' )

def mnMakeWin():

    cmds.window( 'mnWin', title = 'testman', wh=(260,100))

    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=False, columnAlign='center')

    cmds.button( label="Yes,it works",align='center',width=120,height=25, 
                 backgroundColor=[0.5,1,0.5],command='cmds.scriptJob( event=
                   ["SelectionChanged","mnDialog"])')

    cmds.button( label="No, Thank You!",align='center',width=120,height=25, 
                backgroundColor=[1,0.5,0.5],command='cmds.deleteUI("mnWin")')

    cmds.showWindow( 'mnWin' )
```

def mnProgRun():

```
    mnMakeWin()
```

#run

mnProgRun()

Comment: is there a way to still execute the python script as i am sourcing it in the usersetup.mel.

Comment: yes..
as said move your functions to the top scoop level (module level)
then try to source them, like so on my edit